# import file into skype for business calender

Tags: skype, skype-for-business

I created a patient schedule file outside of Skype for business. I want to associate a patient with a selected physician. How can I import the file to the Skype for business calendar? What format should the imported file be?

Comment: I do not got your question, can you improve that? Skype for Business normally replay on Microsoft Exchange when it comes to the calendar. So if you wish to import something into a calendar you need to do that on MS Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Skype for Business does not support its own calendar. Instead, it gets calendar data from the Exchange account of the signed in user. You can easily add a new event to the user's calendar by using the Microsoft Graph RESTful API: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/calendar_post_events